# Copying a part from one embed to another discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create like an Q and A Command. The Problem I ran into is copying the question from the first embed (Question Embed) I created into the second embed (Answer Embed).

My main Problem is that the question in the second embed is always `undefined`

My Code for asking a question:

```js
 case 'f':

            var strf = message.content.slice('.f'.length);

            const qembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setThumbnail('png')
            .setTitle("Question")
            .setColor('WHITE')
            .addFields(
                { name: "Person, that asked the question:", value: `<@!${message.author.id}>` },
                { name: 'Question:', value: `${strf}` },
                { name: 'Channel:', value: `${message.channel}` },
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('If u wanna anwser the question, pls type ".ab"')


            message.channel.send({embeds: [qembed]})

            message.delete()


            break;
```

My Code for anwsering the Question:

```js
case 'ab':
            
            var strfa = message.content.slice(' .ab'.length);
            const abembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setThumbnail('png')
            .setTitle("Anwser")
            .setColor('GREYPLE')
            .addFields(
                {name: "Question", value: `${strf}`},
                {name: "Anwser", value: `${strfa}`},
                {name: "Person, that answered the question", value: `<@!${message.author.id}>`}

            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('If u have any further questions pls let us know')

            message.channel.send({embeds: [abembed]})
            message.delete()
```

Comment: The best way you can do it is to create a collector in your `ask question` command, or if you need someone else to answer your question later - save this question in `database/json file`